# Codeigniter Database Query Telling wrong + formatting

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I select one table but in the error section it show me that I have selected another table.I don't know why this happens.I do query in some view, but there was no problem.This problem was not in everywhere.But in some of view and controller.

Here Was my MY_Model

```
protected function from()
    {
        return $this->db->from($this->_table_name);
    }

    protected function where()
    {
        if(is_array($this->_where))
        {
            foreach($this->_where as $where)
            {
                return $this->db->where($where['field_name'],$where['primary_key']);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            return $this->db->where($this->_field_name,$this->_primary_key);
        }
    }

    protected function or_where()
    {
        if(is_array($this->_where))
        {
            foreach($this->_where as $where)
            {
                return $this->db->or_where($where['field_name'],$where['primary_key']);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            $this->db->or_where($this->_or_field_name,$this->_or_primary_key);
        }
    }

    protected function join()
    {
        if(is_array($this->_join))
        {
            foreach($this->_join as $join)
            {
                return $this->db->join($join['table'],$join['query']);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            return 'Invalid Query';
        }
    }

    protected function order()
    {
        //print_r($this->_order);exit();
        if(is_array($this->_order))
        {
            return $this->db->order_by($this->_order['by'],$this->_order['order']);
        }
        else
        {
            return "Invalid Query";
        }
    }

    protected function limit()
    {
        if(is_array($this->_limit))
        {
            foreach($this->_limit as $limit)
            {
                return $this->db->limit($limit['from'],$limit['to']);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            return $this->db->limit($this->_limit);
        }
    }

    public function get()
    {
        $this->db->select('*');
        if($this->_table_name)
        {
            $this->from();
        }
        if($this->_where || ($this->_field_name && $this->_primary_key))
        {
            $this->where();
        }
        if($this->_or_where || ($this->_or_field_name && $this->_or_primary_key))
        {
            $this->or_where();
        }
        if($this->_join)
        {
            $this->join();
        }
        if($this->_order)
        {
            $this->order();
        }
        if($this->_limit)
        {
            $this->limit();
        }

        return $this->db->get();
    }
```

And this is my query

```
    $this->cm->_table_name = "products";
            $this->cm->_field_name = "products.productID";
            $this->cm->_primary_key = $productID;
            $this->cm->_join = array
            (
                array
                (
                    'table' => 'product_details',
                    'query' => 'products.productID=product_details.productID',
                    'type' => 'left',
                ),
            );
            $data['product'] = $this->cm->get();
```

this is the error

```
Error Number: 1064
```

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '* FROM 'products', 'parentcategory' WHERE 'products'.'productID' = '30'' at line 1

```
SELECT *, * FROM `products`, `parentcategory` WHERE `products`.`productID` = '30'

Filename: C:/xampp/htdocs/mv/system/database/DB_driver.php

Line Number: 691
```

I don't know why this happens please help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change your query with below:

```
SELECT products.*, parentcategory.* FROM `products`, `parentcategory` WHERE `products`.`productID` = '30'
```

or

```
SELECT * FROM `products`, `parentcategory` WHERE `products`.`productID` = '30'
```

You can add another parameter like:

```
$this->cm->_field_to_select = "products.*,parentcategory.*";
```

and add it in your get method

```
if ($this->_field_to_select) {
    $this->db->select($this->_field_to_select);     
}
else {  
    $this->db->select('*');
}
```

Comment: why this happens ?

Comment: i dont put parent category is this query, but this comes automatically .

Comment: as @AbdullaNilam said , because of `$this->db->select('*');` either remove it or provide parameter to set select fields

Comment: so i need to remove $this->db->select('*') from MY_Model or from query ?

Comment: if it is specifically targeting only that query then remove it otherwise add another param to set select fields

Comment: i do this but it still show me i have select other table

$this->cm->_table_name = "products"

but the query shows SELECT * FROM `parentcategory`

Comment: updated my answer to demonstrate, adding conditional select params

Comment: looks like you didn't finish  a previous query - try to write `$this->db->reset_query();` before you call `$this->cm->get();`

Comment: @ArifSajal , if you found this (or other answer) useful then accept answer and close the question so others can know that it has been answered :)